# How to recurse a list of dictionaries into a hierarchical structure using Python?

Tags: python, recursion, hierarchy

This is a small extract of my data structure:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "manager_a",            # doesn't manage any other managers
    "manager": "manager_b",
  },
  {
    "name": "manager_b",
    "manager": "manager_c",
  },
  {
    "name": "manager_c"             # doesn't have a manager
  },
  {
    "name": "manager_d",            # doesn't manage any other managers
    "manager": "manager_c"
  },
  ...
]
```

The result I want is something that shows the hierarchy between the managers. Possibly something like but I'm open to other ideas for how to structure the hierarchy:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "manager_c",            # doesn't have a manager
    "reports": [
       {
         "name": "manager_b",
         "reports": [
           "manager_a"              # doesn't manage any other managers
         ]
       },
       "manager_d"                  # doesn't manage any other managers
    ]
  }
]
```

There are no circular relationships but the manager hierarchy can be several levels deep.

I've tried various things but I'm really struggling to get my head around the recursion.

Comment: The 1st idea that comes to me is to create a 'manager' class, with 3 attributes: 'name', 'reports-to' and 'manages' (this one being a list) and a method 'add_subaltern()' (or whatever you want to name it) and create the instances and relations as you parse the list. In short, parse your list into a tree structure. Then you can add methods to get the chain of command up or down from any manager.

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially what I went with in the end. I also discovered the `treelib` library which makes this super simple.

Answer (score 1):

At the very fundamental level, what you may be looking for is a data structure known as [QuickUnion](https://regenerativetoday.com/union-find-data-structure-part-2-quick-union/), where each "id" is your label "a", "b", "c", etc, and where every individual is connected to zero or more people. The result is a hierarchical tree much like you are envisioning. Give this a try if you don't know what it is yet.